# Restoring the Fuse settings on AVR micro-controller AT32UC3A0512

Tags: bootloader, avr-gcc

Currently I am working on AT32UC3A0512 micro-controller. I have to develop the ethernet bootloader for this. As the bootloader programming needs to make changes in fuse-settings, can anybody suggest me how to restore my fuse settings in case of any problem?

I am using AVR Studio 5 as IDE and AVR Dragon as debugger.

Do anybody has idea how to see the current fuse settings in AVR Studio 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have probably found this by now.

Tools>AVR Programming.

I use jtagice markII myself. With that you can read and set fuses, lockbits, flash, and eeprom.

It's a little buggy in my version, but they may fix it in the future. There seems to be no way to program the device using this tool without wiping the eeprom. You have to download the eeprom first, flash the device, then write the eeprom back.